# PHP: Correct regular expression for making every letter left of the first colon lowercase

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$value='x-Cem-Date:Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:42:28 GMT';
```

Right now I have:

```
$value = preg_replace('/(^.+)(?=:)/e', "strtolower('\\1')", $value);
```

this outputs

```
$value='x-cem-date:wed, 16 dec 2009 15:42:28 GMT';
```

it should output:

```
$value='x-cem-date:Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:42:28 GMT';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression should be as follows:

```
/(^.+?)(?=:)/
```

The difference is the `+?` character. The `+?` is non-greedy, meaning that it will find the LEAST amount of characters until the expression moves onto the next match in the expression, instead of the MOST characters until the next match.

Comment: With the `e`, of course. I dropped that because my RegEx parser doesn't work with the Global, Case Insensitive, Extended, etc. modifiers ON the regular expression.

Comment: Got it.. Which RegEx parser do you use?

Comment: I use RegExr. It's a Flash app that I've found really handy for doing Regular Expressions. It can do Match and Replace pretty effectively. Also, I didn't use `e` when doing the expression. I don't know if that changes it or not, but it found the pattern correctly.

Comment: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ - That's an online version. Let me see if I can find the standalone app.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll probably use that in the future. For others, the link is here: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/ - If you want to install it on your machine. This is what I use.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using `explode()` and `implode()` instead of a regular expression.

```
$value_a = explode( ':', $value );
$value_a[0] = strtolower( $value_a[0] );
$value = implode( ':', $value_a );
```

Comment: Considered that, but in this case I'd prefer regular expressions

Comment: This doesn’t test if there is a colon at all.

Comment: In this case its a series of regular expressions that is applied to the string. I'm trying to be consistent in the design instead of doing a series of regular expressions then using explode.

Comment: @gumbo - OP never said what should happen if there is no colon.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
preg_replace('/([\w-]+?)(:[\w\d\s\:\,]+)/e', "strtolower('\\1') . '\\2'", $value);
```

It works on the example you posted, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, this is the version using `preg_replace_callback`

```
$value='x-Cem-Date:Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:42:28 GMT';

function callback($text){return(strtolower($text[0]));}

echo preg_replace_callback("/^([^:]+:)/","callback",$value);
```

output

```
x-cem-date:Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:42:28 GMT
```

Comment: @stereofrog, you probably right, but in some languages I understand, those kind of things called lambda functions, in php may be its call callback, lamb is name of the function I called. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo preg_replace('~^[^:]+~e', 'strtolower("$0")', $value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try your regular expression with a match

```
$value='x-Cem-Date:Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:42:28 GMT';
$value = preg_match('/(^.+)(?=:)/e', $value, $matches); 
print_r ($matches) . "\n";
```

This should output

```
Array
(
    [0] => x-Cem-Date:Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:42
    [1] => x-Cem-Date:Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:42
)
```

Try this instead

```
$value='x-Cem-Date:Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:42:28 GMT';
$value = preg_replace('/(^.+?:)/e', "strtolower('\\1')", $value);   
echo $value . "\n";
```

The `?` is in there so the regex isn't greedy and grabbing more than it should.