# PHP preg_replace: help me grok (?=:)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915615/), there are the following lines:

```
$value='x-Cem-Date:Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:42:28 GMT';
$value = preg_replace('/(^.+?)(?=:)/e', "strtolower('\\1')", $value);
// yields 'x-cem-date:Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:42:28 GMT'
```

That `(?=:)` bit indicates a search for the colon, it has to.  But, I don't understand that particular syntax, with the `?=`.  What exactly is going on there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It looks whether the particular subexpression occurs *after* that point. But it doesn't *consume* anything in the match:

> Positive lookahead works just the same. `q(?=u)` matches a `q` that is followed by a `u`, without making the `u` part of the match. The positive lookahead construct is a pair of round brackets, with the opening bracket followed by a question mark and an equals sign. —[RegularExpressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

As you may notice, lookaround is especially helpful when replacing text since you don't need to include the surrounding environment into the replacement text. For example, to replace every `q` that is not followed by a `u` with `qu` you can do

```
replace 'q([^u])' by 'qu\1'
```

but this captures the following character because it's part of the match and re-inserts it later again. You can also use lookaround:

```
replace 'q(?!u)' by 'qu'
```

where only the q gets matched and replaced, so including part of the match in the replacement string isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: Ah yes. It "matches without including". Thanks for putting a name to it.